# Apt broken install

Tags: debian, apt

I have upgraded from debian 8, 9, then subsequently 10 over the last few days. At some point in this process, apt quit functioning because it cannot upgrade a gnuplot package (which I am sure I'm not using in the first place). I'm about to pull my hair out as I've been searching for a solution a while now.

```
○ → apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnuplot-nox : Depends: gnuplot-data (= 5.2.6+dfsg1-1+deb10u1) but 4.6.6-2+deb8u1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

```
○ → apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gnuplot-data
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gnuplot-data
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/180 kB of archives.
After this operation, 37.9 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 138120 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gnuplot-data_5.2.6+dfsg1-1+deb10u1_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnuplot-data (5.2.6+dfsg1-1+deb10u1) over (4.6.6-2+deb8u1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gnuplot-data_5.2.6+dfsg1-1+deb10u1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/gnuplot/gnuplot-lua-tikz-common.tex', which is also in package gnuplot-tex 4.6.6-2+deb8u1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gnuplot-data_5.2.6+dfsg1-1+deb10u1_all.deb
```

Additionally, I don't think this is related but may be worth mentioning, my kernel will not upgrade (presumably because of broken apt). I'll look for a solution down the road as to not derail the original intended question.

```
Linux ****.com 3.10.0-1127.10.1.vz7.162.5 #1 SMP Thu Jun 18 20:32:03 MSK 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux

cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
```

linux headers 5.6 and 5.7 are showing in my apt cache. I think the broken gnuplot is not letting me upgrade? Any tips?
I have rebooted several times in between upgrades. I would really just like to remove the package all together and get apt working again

Comment: I would try to uninstall all gnuplot* packages and re-install them. If apt does not let you uninstall gnuplot uninstall them directly via dpkg.

Comment: dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq gnuplot gives an error " Package gnuplot-nox which provides gnuplot is not configured yet."... may that be why it is failing? can i restart the configuration of that package?

Comment: success with deleting the folder as mentioned in this answered question -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431372/removing-broken-packages-in-ubuntu

Comment: Open terminal and run `sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt autoclean`

Answer (score 1):

check on this Debian Bug to find the solution
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=826701

In short:

dpkg -i --force-overwrite  "file"

apt-get install -f